# Simple payback function out of gas

Tags: solidity, remix, testrpc

I have very basic contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Test {
    function() public payable {
    }

    function pay(uint _amount) public returns (uint) {
        require(this.balance >= _amount);
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

Once started on Remix with JavascriptVM it works as expected - payable function receives ethers and `pay` pay it to any address. But when I connect Remix to the locally running `testrpc` or to `Rinkeby` network this contract fails on line with `transfer` call with error `transact to Test.pay errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`.

I tried to replace `transfer` with `send` without any luck.

Of course I and trying to pay less then current contract balance (sent 10 ETH, trying to pay out 5 ETH).

**UPD:**

It is damn strange, but almost same contract works:

```
contract Test {

    event Event(string _msg, address _address, uint _amount);

    function() public payable {
    }

    function pay(uint _amount) public returns (uint256) {
        require(this.balance >= _amount);

        _pay(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function _pay(address _to, uint _amount) private {
        _to.transfer(_amount);
        Event("Outcome", _to, _amount);
    }
}
```

BUT! If I remove mentions of `Event` - it stops works with the same error!

**UPD2:** It becomess stranger and stranger. If in contract that works I remove `returns (uint256)` it stop working too. I am totally confues - why return value affects contract work? Why separated logic works and merged into one function - no?

Comment: What is the gas limit that you set? Do you have a link to transaction on rinkeby?

Comment: Is `msg.sender` a contract? When sending ether to a contract using transfer the gas is limited to 2300 'gas stipend' as a security measure. To allow more gas you have to use the low level `call`, like this `require(msg.sender.call.value(_amount).gas(_gas)());`

Comment: @medvedev1088 default one for transfer from contract.

Comment: @Ismael no, msg.sender is user's address.

Comment: @AlexG.P. I mean the gaslimit that you set for the transaction

Comment: @medvedev1088 `32144`. For second contract function `pay` works with the same gas limit, so it is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @AlexG.P. transfer function costs 9700 so it may be that the provided gas limit is not sufficient. Do you have a link to the transaction on Rinkeby?

Comment: @medvedev1088 https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xecfe452d8e7c539a3ee8a66a56cac5db9423aea6

Comment: @medvedev1088 9700 < 37144

Comment: @AlexG.P. you need to add intrinsic gas and gas for computations, it might be very close to the gas limit you set. All the transactions in the link yo provided are successful.

Comment: @medvedev1088 yes, now I see that all tx are ok but nevertheless when this contract created on locally running testrpc it fails. It hasn't any additional computation/logic.

Comment: It's a bug of Remix. Try to use `truffle console`. It works for me with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`out of gas` error *sometimes* means that there is not enough gas to complete the transaction.

While before the introduction of `REVERT` opcode `out of gas` error could appear in case of a throw as it consumed all gas, with `REVERT` this error is more reliable and you can assume with high probability that it's an actual `out of gas` and not some other exception.

Try increasing the gas limit for your transaction and see if it works.